# nginx conf for tonic rest with multiple sites on mac

Tags: macos, rest, nginx, tonic

i try to config nginx with tonic rest for multiple sites on my mac.
My nginx runs as localhost on my mac.

My root is /Users/thorsten/Sites

In root i habe some projects e.g. /project1, /project2

Each project has the tonic rest folder /standard/rest...

In nginx.conf i try

```
location /rest/ {
        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;         # Pass the http authorization parameter to the PHP script
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /rest/dispatch.php?/$1 last;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Nothing happend. 
Do i need a config for each project or can i have a global config for all project e.g. $project/rest/...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config works for me

```
  location ~ ^/(?<project>.+)/standard/rest/ {
    fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
    include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$project/standard/rest/dispatch.php?/$1 last;
            break;
    }
}
```